# How to detect Multiple occurrences of same objects in an image using Feature detection

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, feature-detection

Is there any possible way to detect multiple occurrences of same object in an image using feature detection?

Earlier I tried it with Template Matching and I was able to detect the multiple occurrences but later I dropped because of its dependency on image orientation and size.

[Single Occurrence of ocject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CFqe.png)

[Multiple Occurrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XKzn.png)

[Question about template matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255339/how-can-i-detect-multiple-occurrence-of-of-an-object-in-an-image)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using OpenCVForUnity;

namespace OpenCVForUnitySample
{
public class Feature2DSample : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start ()
    {
        Texture2D imgTemplate = Resources.Load ("lena") as Texture2D;
        Texture2D imgTexture = Resources.Load ("yVLsd_") as Texture2D;

        Mat matSrc = new Mat (imgTemplate.height, imgTemplate.width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
        Utils.texture2DToMat (imgTemplate, matSrc);
        Debug.Log ("img1Mat dst ToString " + matSrc.ToString ());

        Mat matScene = new Mat (imgTexture.height, imgTexture.width, CvType.CV_8UC3);
        Utils.texture2DToMat (imgTexture, matScene);
        Debug.Log ("img2Mat dst ToString " + matScene.ToString ());

        FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create (FeatureDetector.ORB);
        DescriptorExtractor extractor = DescriptorExtractor.create (DescriptorExtractor.ORB);

        MatOfKeyPoint keypointsSrc = new MatOfKeyPoint ();
        Mat descriptorsSrc = new Mat ();

        detector.detect (matSrc, keypointsSrc);
        extractor.compute (matSrc, keypointsSrc, descriptorsSrc);

        MatOfKeyPoint keypointsScene = new MatOfKeyPoint ();
        Mat descriptorsScene = new Mat ();

        detector.detect (matScene, keypointsScene);
        extractor.compute (matScene, keypointsScene, descriptorsScene);

        DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create (DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMINGLUT);
        MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch ();

        matcher.match (descriptorsSrc, descriptorsScene, matches);

        //NEW CODE
        List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList ();

        //– Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
        double max_dist = 0;
        double min_dist = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < descriptorsSrc.rows (); i++) {
            double dist = (double)matchesList [i].distance;

            if (dist < min_dist)
                min_dist = dist;
            if (dist > max_dist)
                max_dist = dist;
        }

        List<DMatch> good_matches = new List<DMatch> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < descriptorsSrc.rows (); i++) {
            if (matchesList [i].distance < 3 * min_dist) {
                good_matches.Add (matchesList [i]);
            }
        }
        MatOfDMatch gm = new MatOfDMatch ();
        gm.fromList (good_matches);

        List<Point> objList = new List<Point> ();
        List<Point> sceneList = new List<Point> ();

        List<KeyPoint> keypoints_objectList = keypointsSrc.toList ();
        List<KeyPoint> keypoints_sceneList = keypointsScene.toList ();

        for (int i = 0; i < good_matches.Count; i++) {
            objList.Add (keypoints_objectList [good_matches [i].queryIdx].pt);
            sceneList.Add (keypoints_sceneList [good_matches [i].trainIdx].pt);
        }

        MatOfPoint2f obj = new MatOfPoint2f ();
        MatOfPoint2f scene = new MatOfPoint2f ();

        obj.fromList (objList); 
        scene.fromList (sceneList);

        Mat H = Calib3d.findHomography (obj, scene);
        Mat warpimg = matSrc.clone ();

        Mat srcRectMat = new Mat (4, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
        Mat dstRectMat = new Mat (4, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);

        Point[] obj_corners = new Point[4];
        obj_corners [0] = new Point (0, 0);
        obj_corners [1] = new Point ((double)matSrc.cols (), 0);
        obj_corners [2] = new Point (matSrc.cols (), matSrc.rows ()); 
        obj_corners [3] = new Point (0, matSrc.rows ());

        Point[] scene_corners = new Point [4];

        MatOfPoint2f srcPointMat = new MatOfPoint2f (obj_corners);
        MatOfPoint2f dstPointMat = new MatOfPoint2f ();

        Core.perspectiveTransform (srcPointMat, dstPointMat, H);
        scene_corners = dstPointMat.toArray ();
        Mat resultImg = new Mat ();
        Features2d.drawMatches (matSrc, keypointsSrc, matScene, keypointsScene, matches, resultImg);

        Core.line (resultImg, AddPoints (scene_corners [0], new Point ((double)matSrc.cols (), 0)), AddPoints (scene_corners [1], new Point ((double)matSrc.cols (), 0)), new Scalar (0, 255, 0), 4);
        Core.line (resultImg, AddPoints (scene_corners [1], new Point ((double)matSrc.cols (), 0)), AddPoints (scene_corners [2], new Point ((double)matSrc.cols (), 0)), new Scalar (0, 255, 0), 4);
        Core.line (resultImg, AddPoints (scene_corners [2], new Point ((double)matSrc.cols (), 0)), AddPoints (scene_corners [3], new Point ((double)matSrc.cols (), 0)), new Scalar (0, 255, 0), 4);
        Core.line (resultImg, AddPoints (scene_corners [3], new Point ((double)matSrc.cols (), 0)), AddPoints (scene_corners [0], new Point ((double)matSrc.cols (), 0)), new Scalar (0, 255, 0), 4);


        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D (resultImg.cols (), resultImg.rows (), TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
        Utils.matToTexture2D (resultImg, texture);
        gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.mainTexture = texture;

    }

    Point AddPoints (Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        return new Point (p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: have a look at my answers in these two questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34310914/recognize-recurring-images-into-a-larger-one?lq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543880/how-to-find-euclidean-distance-between-keypoints-of-a-single-image-in-opencv/26547225#26547225

Comment: if you know the object you want to detect multiple times you should just compute the matching differently: instead of choosing best match, use n-best matches for each feature